# Append nested JSON object key to loop - Convert JSON to input field values dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, nested-loops

So I have a loop that appends the JSON value to their input via their key as ID. I'm having trouble accessing the nested JSON object "tax_lines" and attaching it to the respective input. Maybe there is a different way I should be doing this?

data.json

```
{
   "purchase_order" :[
     { 
        "id": "1",
        "external_number": "1000",
        "status": "Created",
        "tax_lines": [ 
            {
               "name": "GST",
               "rate": "0.05",
            }
        ],
        "price_list": [
            {
               "id": "msrp",
               "name": "retail price",
               "currency": "USD"
        ],
 .....etc
   ]
}
```

```
<input id="external_number" />
<input id="id"/>
<input id="status" />
<input id="tax_lines_name" />
<input id="tax_lines_rate" />


<script>
    const data_file = 'data.json';

    function fetchPO() {
        fetch(data_file).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((data => {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.purchase_orders.length; i++) {
                    data.purchase_orders.forEach((PODetails) => {
                        Object.keys(PODetails).map(value => {
                            document.getElementBy(value.replace(/ /g, "")).value = PODetails[value];
                        })

                        PODetails.tax_lines.forEach((tax) => {
                            Object.keys(tax).map(value => {
                                document.getElementByID(value.replace(/ /g, "")).value = tax[value];
                            })
                        })
                    })

                }
            })
        }

</script>
```

**To clarify, in short, how can I translate a json object's data to html inputs dynamically?**

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo but you have var 1 = 0 in your for loop.

Comment: Your "JSON" is invalid (missing the `"` on `purchase_order"`, missing the ending brackets for several structures). Also, once it has been parsed, it's no longer JSON, it's just objects. See [There's no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fiddle in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ycj08Lk/3/) for a full example.

You had a number of errors:

1. Using a var i = 0 for loop (since you're using a foreach loop inside)
2. Sometimes your value item in the first Object.keys() is a object and so can't set it to an input field.
3. Using .map() is an antipattern when you don't want a returned array.

To fix this, you can use the snippet below.

```
<input id="external_number" /><br />
<input id="id" /><br />
<input id="status" /><br />
<input id="tax_lines_name" /><br />
<input id="tax_lines_rate" /><br />


<script>
  async function get() {

    return `
{
  "purchase_order": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "external_number": "10001",
      "status": "Created",
      "tax_lines": [
        {
          "name": "GST",
          "rate": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
        `;
  }

  function fetchPO() {
    get()
      .then(response => JSON.parse(response))
      .then(data => {

      data.purchase_order.forEach((PODetails) => {
        Object.keys(PODetails).forEach(value => {
                    if (value !== 'tax_lines') {
              document.getElementById(value.replace(/ /g, "")).value = PODetails[value];
          }
        })

        PODetails.tax_lines.forEach((tax) => {
          Object.keys(tax).forEach(value => {
            document.getElementById('tax_lines_' + value).value = tax[value];
          })
        }) 
      })


      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      })
  }

  fetchPO();

</script>
```

EDIT: Updated the code segment since jsfiddle is not working for you. Please have a look if the data you have is similar in structure as the data I am using. Also modified getting data statically not with fetch.

EDIT 2: Further to the responses in the comments section, to achieve fully dynamic form fill up, you need to be flexible over the input ids. The [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbsatter/o4ma1hvc/) is updated and handles the input json fully dynamically. So, an object:

```
{
   "id": "some-id",
   "name": "sbsatter",
   "grades": [
        {
            "course": "CS555",
            "grade": "A"
        },
        {
            "course": "CS666",
            "grade": "B"
        }
    ]
```

will result dynamically in inputs with ids:

1. id
2. name
3. grades_0_course
4. grades_0_grade
5. grades_1_course
6. grades_1_grade

It is easier to handle the json tree recursively. You may need to handle the more specific cases (such as inputs being integers, etc). Here's the function that achieves that:

```
        function handleObject(obj, name) {
          // console.log('Handling obj: ', obj, 'name: ', name);
          
          if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object String]') {
            // create input and update
            // document.getElementById(name + '_' + key).value = obj[key];
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.id = name.substring(1);
            input.value = obj;
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(input);
            console.log(name.substring(1), obj);
          } 
          else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]') {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
                handleObject(obj[key], name + "_" + key);
            });
          }
          else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
            obj.forEach((object, idx) => {
              Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
                handleObject(object[key], name + "_" + key + "_" + idx);
              });
            });
          }
        }
        
        handleObject(data, '');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation and the fiddle. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work. The code breaks at the forEach((tax). I couldn't console.log(tax); I get an error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" even though my JSON file has no NULL values.

Comment: @webdevelopern00b I updated the code here. Can you check your data has format as shown above?

Comment: I updated my JSON before, sorry I should have mentioned it. My JSON file has other nested keys and values. The code you gave me works for the JSON I initially showed and with your fiddle but not for my entire file. I need to be able to loop through my entire JSON file and assign values to their respective inputs

Comment: @webdevelopern00b You need to adjust according to the other fields you have. For instance, you can replace value !== 'tax_lines' with a condition more appropriate. I updated the fiddle so you can take a look at how I'm reading for each of the strings values in the json. You can use separate segments for other json objs and arrays (as done in tax_lines), or make it fully dynamic. Unless you have a problem with the data above, I suggest you update the question as appropriate.

Comment: @webdevelopern00b I'm just seeing the updated data now. Can you specify what you're trying to achieve? I think with some modification of the code above, you can handle them properly.

Comment: I'd like to make it fully dynamic, whereas the function loops through the entire json file and appends the value to their key via their ID. But I don't think this is possible with the way I'm doing it now. I don't know if there was a better way of achieving this, where data gets displaying in specific spots.

Comment: As a matter of fact, that can be done. But you need to be flexible with the input ids. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @webdevelopern00b also pls mark this as the correct answer and upvote if it helps.

Comment: YES. Thank you so much for your help